# Adding two actions in one windows task job with chef` windows_task

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

How to add two actions in single scheduled task using windows_tasks in chef?

[Chef documentation](https://docs.chef.io/resource_windows_task.html) doesn't show any option to add multiple actions in single task

I want something like this

```
    windows_task 'TestJob' do
      command "powershell c:\\jobs\\Test1.ps1"
      **command "powershell c:\\jobs\\Test2.ps1"**
      cwd 'C:\\'
      run_level :highest
      frequency :hourly
      frequency_modifier 1
      start_time '00:01'
      start_day '01/01/2000'
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

you should either:

1. combine your scripts into a single one
2. have 2 different `windows_task` resource for each of which